# Simple JS code for highlighting search text in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to rewrite [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/FutureWebDev/HfS7e/) to suit my needs, but I am lost in all the replacing magic that the auther of the Fiddle does. Here's my [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmuzynf0/).

My goal is to find all occurrances of "a" letter in the paragraph and highlight them. I just can't figure out why my letters are just being replaced by `1$` instead of being highlighted. Can anyone help me with this ?

HTML

```
<div id="searchtext">
  <p>I want to highlight all "a" letters in this paragraph</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var text = 'a';
      var query = new RegExp(text, "gim");
      var e = document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML;
      var enew = e.replace(/(<span>|<\/span>)/igm, "");
      document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = enew;
      var newe = enew.replace(query, "<span>1$</span>");
      document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = newe;
    });
```

CSS:

```
#searchtext span {
  background-color: #FF9;
  color: #555;
}
```

Comment: `'1$' != '$1'`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\$&` instead

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var text = 'a';
      var query = new RegExp(text, "gim");
      var e = document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML;
      var enew = e.replace(/(<span>|<\/span>)/igm, "");
      document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = enew;
      var newe = enew.replace(query, "<span>\$&</span>");
      document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = newe;
    });
```

```css
#searchtext span {
  background-color: #FF9;
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchtext">
  <p>I want to highlight all "a" letters in this paragraph</p>
</div>
```

[More information about $&](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastMatch)

Comment: Can you add an explanation what `\$&` does ?

Comment: @Nick I think `$&` is used as the replacement pattern, [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) , rather then the last RegEx match (the link you posted).